# Should a one person team use a process model?

Tags: development-process, solo-development

I am about to start work on my biggest project yet (about 6 months full time work). For previous projects as they were only short I never intentionally used a model, I may have done but I didn't set out to do it.

So... Before I start this project would it be advised to try and use some model? And if it is then what do you think would be useful to a 1 person team?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a young guy fresh out of the college - i never used to use Source control.  However, now after having used to SCM, even if i do the project alone it makes life easier by using SVN. Imagine how easy it is to retrieve yesterdays' work if i mess up the code - and also take a look back of how things evolve. I don't have to keep all this in my mind.

This questions usually arrive because lot of times people think of *Process* they think of a lot of documentation, and whole bunch of formalities that looks like a waste of time. Yes, if you are alone, don't do anything which looks like a waste of time. (In fact in our company i leave people to question the proces and don't do it if it is a waste of time; but that is probably too much of stretch).

The point is: in a true sense a process is a tool, a mechanism that will ensure that simple mistakes (rather goof-ups) don't happen and don't create disasters-

- A seasoned carpenter will always measure and remeasure the wood before putting a cut,
- A good driver will always put the seat belt on while driving,
- A good chef of a restaurent will have a simple way to test food
- -- the sameway a good programmer will check-in the code before he goes back to sleep.

The complexity of the tool varies, but it is always important that practices are used in the way that helps you and it is really nothing about being alone or in the team.

Answer (score 2):

I would.

It does not need to be a heavy process, you can probably keep it quite light.

But it will allow you proper tracking through each stage of the lifecycle and provide proof of how you got to where you're going for management.

It will also be useful should someone else join your project mid-stream or for a phase 2, however unlikely you think this is just now.